# PHP add items to catalog using array_push function in a class

Tags: php, class, oop

how can I add items from "a.php" to an array in "catalogus.php" using array_push?

This is "a.php"

```
<?php

include("Catalogus.php");


$product1 = new Product(); 
$product1->setNaam("Muis");     



$catalogus = new Catalogus();

$value = $product1;
voegProductToe($value);

  ?>
```

this is "catalogus.php"

```
 <?php

class Catalogus{
var $producten;


$producten = array();

function voegProductToe($value){
        array_push( $this->producten, "$value");

}

}


  ?>
```

I got an error when trying to run this

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$producten' (T_VARIABLE), expecting `function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Catalogus.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

The line `$producten = array();` doesn't belong.  If you're trying to define the property $producten as an empty array, use the assignment operator on the same line.

```
class Catalogus{
    var $producten = array();
```

I'd highly recommend using the visibility keywords like `private`, `protected` or `public` instead of `var` for property definitions.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your php class. For starter, var ins't needed in PHP. You could make your array public or have a public function that pushes in the array. Also welcome to SO.

```
 class Catalogus{

      public $producten = [];
      /*OR*/
      public function addToCatalog($__item){
          $this->producten[] = $__item;
      }
 }

 $catalogus = new Catalogus();

 $catalogus->producten[] = $value;
 /*OR*/
 $catalogus->addToCatalog($value);
```

Comment: Just a note, a function without visibility and a property declared with `var` are already treated as public

Comment: I think it's gonna help him more figure out public, private, protected keywords this way than letting him use var

Comment: Right, but saying `var` isn't needed might be confusing.